# Curve fitting for each pixel in an image series

Tags: matlab, curve-fitting

I have a 3d array for size (1236,1626,20)-Its a series of 20 images. 
Now, I want to fit a curve to each pixel in the image.

1) The code below does the job but takes huge amount of time. I want to increase the speed of execution. Let me know how this can be done.

```
pCell=cell(1236,1626);
for x=1:1:1236
    for y=1:1:1626
        fx=phaseMat(x,y,1:20);
        fy=reshape(fx,[],20);
        pCell{x,y}=fit(fy',set(:),'poly4');
    end
end
```

2) Also, How can I save this polynomial matrix in a file for future use.

Comment: It takes time. It will. Probably you can speed up the computation, but fitting that huge amount of data just takes time. Specially if you are fitting a `poly4`. I reccomend you have a look to other fitting methods. See some examples in : http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/interp1.html

Comment: Do you have the parallel computing toolbox available?